# AngularJS : Unable to make application URL case insensitive in angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular-ui-router in my angular application. I want to make URLs in my application case insensitive. I explored in stack overflow and one of the answers here suggested me to use this code in the app config:

```
$urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
        //what this function returns will be set as the $location.url
        var path = $location.path(), normalized = path.toLowerCase();
        if (path != normalized) {
            //instead of returning a new url string, I'll just change the $location.path directly so I don't have to worry about constructing a new url string and so a new state change is not triggered
            $location.replace().path(normalized);
        }
        // because we've returned nothing, no state change occurs
        //return $location.absUrl(normalized);
    });
```

However it doesn't work for me and my application returns back to the home page(when trying to alter the case in URL) since my default router page setting is (/Home). When the url changes, I want the code to load the corresponding template and invoke its corresponding controller. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: instaed of $location..replace().path(normalized); use $location.replace().path(normalized);

Comment: that's a mistake while copying into question. I've corrected it.

Comment: I still have the problem. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but it might still help someone who is facing a similar issue.

Since you are normalizing the URL to lowercase, make sure the URL in your state configurations is also lower case.

For example, this will not work:

```
$stateProvider.state('state1', { url: '/STATE1' ...
```

This will work:

```
$stateProvider.state('state1', { url: '/state1' ...
```

Comment: URL in state configuration was in lower case itself. But it wasn't working for me.